How to merge branches containing git submodule correctly in Azure
According to azure-devops-branching-strategy, I want to merge a hotfix branch created from master correctly back to develop.
I have two git code modules: ACU1 and ACU2 which both use git submodule COMMON
The problem now is that if on develop branch on the hotfix branch the submodule COMMONM changed at the same time, there is always trouble while merging this.
Therefore, the question how to do this correctly, and if there is a recommended way.
What I do so far:

Make a pull-request (let's say PR1) hotfix COMMON -> develop COMMON
Merge the pull-request PR1 via Merge type: Merge (no fast forward)
Now I get a new commit ID on COMMON with the merged changes. (So far so good)

Now how to merge ACU1 and ACU2 correctly?

Make a pull-request hotfix ACU1 -> develop ACU1 shows merge conflict on submodule COMMON now.

How to tell Azure to take COMMON from the new commit ID created on PR1?
What is the best practice to merge to merge projects containing submodules in Azure? (Is it correct first do the PR on COMMON with Merge (no fast forward), then the other modules, or is there a better preferred way?)

The steps you have done:

Make a pull-request (let's say PR1) hotfix COMMON -> develop COMMON
Merge the pull-request PR1 via Merge type: Merge (no fast forward)
Now I get a new commit ID on COMMON with the merged changes. (So far so good)

To merge ACU1 and ACU2 without merge conflict on submodule COMMON, you can refer the following steps:

Update the submodule reference in the develop and hotfix branches to point to the new commit ID of the submodule. After this step, the submodule is the same commit in both branches.

For example, you can run the following git command
git checkout <branch-name>  # branch-name: develop , hotfix
cd <submodule-path>  # submodule-path: COMMONM 
git checkout <commit-id>   #the new commit ID on COMMON you get in the step 3
cd ..
git add <submodule-path> 
git commit -m "Update submodule COMMONM to specific commit ID"
git push origin <branch-name>


Now you can make a pull-request hotfix ACU1 -> develop ACU1 without merge conflict on submodule COMMON.

Update
According to the Successful Git Branching Model in the azure-devops-branching-strategy you mentioned in the question, the hotfix branch and the develop branch are both created from the same master branch initial production version. They should have the same submodule COMMON initially.

It seems that you or your team member later changed the version of the submodule COMMON in the hotfix and develop branches. This caused the pull request hotfix-ACU1 -> develop-ACU1 to show a merge conflict on the submodule COMMON.
Maybe you can explore if it is necessary to change the submodule COMMON on the develop branch. If the submodule COMMON is not changed in the develop branch, there will be no merge conflict on submodule COMMON in the pull-request hotfix ACU1 -> develop ACU1.

Good approach,thank you... But is it also possible only with Azure Tooling? So I don´t want to modify the hotfix branch to point to an other COMMON submodule. Also I am not allowed to push changes on develop branch directly without pull request.

Hi @MaKruQ, if you are not allowed to push changes on develop branch directly without pull request, you can create a new branch from the develop branch (e.g., update-submodule-common), and update the submodule COMMON in this branch to point to the new commit ID created in PR1 using the commands in step 4. Then, you can create a pull request from update-submodule-common to develop to update the develop branch with the new commit ID. Also, I updated the answer with more information, please check. Thanks!
